# Using location.replace with data from a form

Tags: javascript, string, html, forms

I have an HTML form that I am trying to use to navigate to a different page. I was trying to use `window.location.replace` to append the value of the input to the end of the form like this:

> Before: https://example.com/search
>
> After: https://example.com/search/formvalue

I have tried just about every trick I can find, but have had no luck. I was able to get it working by replacing `window.location.replace` with `window.open`, but I don't want to have to open it in a new tab. I also tried `window.location.assign` but had no more luck with that. I tried running both of these functions in the Chrome console and they worked fine from there. My code is below.

```js
function onenter() {
  var term = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
  window.location.replace("/search/" + term);
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" onsubmit="onenter();">
  <input id="searchbox" name="term" type="text" autofocus>
  <button id="searchenter" type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: This may help you if you are trying to do something similar. [How to modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-to-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the form submission reloads the page. Use `eventObject.preventDefault`:

```js
function onenter(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var term = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
  window.location.replace("/search/" + term);
  console.log(window.location);
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" onsubmit="onenter(e);">
  <input id="searchbox" name="term" type="text" autofocus>
  <button id="searchenter" type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```